# Disable Date from NowDate to minus five years in datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I Have a Requirement on the DOB, that is DOB Validation should be from NowDate() to minus Five years.for example: if am going to open today's date in DatePicker, that should be open from minus years before onwards to back, here validation should be who have below 5 years they cannot register here.Is this possible in JQuery. Can u please tell me how can i do.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question: are you looking for a way to validate DOBs or have the datepicker only show the past 5 years? both?

Comment: Hi Sphaso, Thanks for Reply, I am looking for both?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery DatePicker has mindate option, use it to set your min date as required:

```
$("input.DateFrom").datepicker({
minDate: //Put your min date calculation here,
...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function($) {
    var day = new Date(),
        year = ((day.getMonth() - 2) < 0) ? (day.getFullYear() - 5) : day.getFullYear(),
        month = ((day.getMonth()) < 0) ? (12 + (day.getMonth())) : (day.getMonth() + 1),
        date = day.getDate() + '-' + month + '-' + year;
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        defaultDate: '-2m'
    }).val(date);
});
```